# can't upload a .png file of a graph using slack.api

Tags: python, matplotlib, slack, slack-api

It had 2 functions, one created a graph, the other sent the graph in .png format and text to the telegram bot.
Now I rewrote it for slack and got a problem.
The message comes, but the .png file of the graph does not.
I get an Error:
File upload failed.
Error: invalid_auth

Although he gave access to add files and messages:
1.files:write - Upload, edit, and delete files as roman_test
2. incoming-webhook - Post messages to specific channels in Slack

Below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/*****'
SLACK_CHANNEL = "#test-channel"
SLACK_TOKEN = '******2'

def alert_to_slack(plot_object=None, caption=None):
    files = {
        'file': plot_object
    }
    payload = {
        'filename': plot_object.name,
        'token': SLACK_TOKEN,
        'channels': SLACK_CHANNEL
    }

    response = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', params=payload, files=files)
    data = response.json()

    if response.status_code == 200 and data['ok']:
        file_url = data['file']['url_private']
        print(f"File uploaded successfully. URL: {file_url}")
    else:
        print("File upload failed.")
        print(f"Error: {data['error']}")

    data = {
        "text": f"*Spending Sum Alert Manager*\n\n{caption}",
        "username": "Spending",
        "channel": SLACK_CHANNEL,
        "mrkdwn": True
    }

    r = requests.post(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, json=data)
    return r.status_code


def slack_send():
    # Get the text and number of days between the last day in the DataFrame and the prediction day
    text = 'hahahaha'

    # Sample data for the x-axis
    dates = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', end='2023-12-31', freq='D')

    # Sample data for the y-axis
    values = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(dates))  # Your data

    # Create a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': dates, 'y': values})

    # Set the size of the plot
    sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (16, 8)})

    # Create a line plot based on the DataFrame
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='ds', y='y', color='#1c1c1c')

    # Set the labels for the x-axis and y-axis
    ax.set_xlabel('date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Spending sum')

    # Set the title of the plot
    plt.title(f'Alert in Spending sum', size=16)

    # Adjust the plot layout
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Save the plot to a BytesIO object
    plot_object = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(plot_object)
    plot_object.seek(0)
    plot_object.name = 'alert.png'
    plt.close()

    # Send the plot and text information as a response to the message
    alert_to_slack(plot_object=plot_object, caption=text)


slack_send()
```

Comment: Try `data=payload` instead of `params=payload`...

Comment: @AKX
File upload failed.
Error: channel_not_found
As I understand it, it has become better, now the only question is how to transfer the channel, etc.

Comment: It **seems** like your are sending a BytesIO object, not a `.png`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney how do I check if it's a .png or not?

Comment: I already ran an example with your code `type(plot_object) → _io.BytesIO`

Comment: `plt.savefig('test.png')` and then send the file

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Oh shit, really, it's so simple, I'll try to save it as a png now

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney but I have an error about authorization, not .png. although I agree the file should be in this format

Comment: I'd verify at https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload, that it's configured correctly.